# customise jQuery totemticker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [totemticker](http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/totem/index.html) jQuery plugin, but need to be able to stop it programatically. It doesn't seem to provide this feature, so I had a look at [the source code](https://github.com/buildinternet/totem/blob/master/js/jquery.totemticker.js) to see if I could add it myself.

It seems that all I need to do is figure out how to call

```
base.stop_interval()
```

However, I can't seem to make the object that is stored in `base` accessible to callers. I've made a couple of unsuccesful atttempts, but hopefully someone who knows a bit more about how jQuery plugins work can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a line in the source here:

```
base.$el.data("omr.totemticker", base);
```

What it's basically doing is making the base object available to the jQuery object through the data function.

Select it with jQuery and call `.data('omr.totemticker')` to get the `base` object out.

This is the inspection (In Chrome's Dev tools) of the demo you linked to.

[image: The Example Inspected]

So calling `$("#vertical-ticker").data("omr.totemticker").stop_interval();` should stop the auto-rotation of the ticker.